# Using node.js 'util' to promisify is returning an error

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to create a function in a file to return a promis, which I will call form another file. I'm trying to use the 'util.promisify' to wrap the function, but I'm getting an error. Here is the code and the error:

from my 'checkEmail.js':

```
const Profile = require('../../models/profile');
const util = require('util');


var exports = module.exports = {};

exports.findEmail = util.promisify(checkEmail());


 function checkEmail (email) {
   Profile.findOne({ 'emails': { $elemMatch: { email_address: email } } }, (err, userEmail) => {
    let conclusion = false;
    if (err) {
      console.log('Error in looking up an existing email');
    } else {
      if (userEmail) {
        console.log('We found an existing owner for email: ' + email);
        conclusion = true;
      }
    }
      return conclusion;
  })
 }
```

Calling it on 'profile.js':

```
router.route('/addemail/:id')

  // ADD EMAILS
  .put(function (req, res) {


    Profile.findOne({ 'owner_id': req.params.id }, function (err, profile) {
      if (err)
        res.send(err);

      EmailCheck.findEmail(req.body.email_address).then((data)=>{ 
        console.log('The answer is: ', data);
      });

      profile.emails.push({
        email_type: req.body.email_type,
        email_address: req.body.email_address
      })
      profile.save(function (err) {
        if (err)
          res.send(err);
        res.json(profile);
      });
    });
  });
```

The error I'm getting is:

```
Config for: http://localhost:3000
internal/util.js:272
    throw new ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE('original', 'Function', original);
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to promisify the function that you pass to `util.promisify` must:

> Take a function following the common error-first callback style, i.e.
>   taking a (err, value) => callback as the **last argumen**t, and returns a version that returns promise

So you can either promisify `Profile.findOne`, or pass a callback as the last argument to `checkEmail`

```
function checkEmail (email, callback) {
   Profile.findOne({ 'emails': { $elemMatch: { email_address: email } } }, (err, userEmail) => {
    let conclusion = false;
    if (err)
      return callback(new Error('Error in looking up an existing email'));

    if (userEmail) {
      console.log('We found an existing owner for email: ' + email);
      conclusion = true;
    }
    return callback(null, conclusion);
  })
 }
```

And then you should call it like this:

```
exports.findEmail = util.promisify(checkEmail);
```

Otherwise you're passing to `.promisify` the returned value of `checkEmail` which is not a function following the style commented above.

Answer (score 0):

You have typo, use `util.promisify(checkEmail)` instead, parentheses are redundant

Comment: It's not really a typo, and they're not redundant, they do two different things. And it will still not work.

Comment: @rashad Thanks. But my problem now is that I'm not getting anything on the result side. What could I be doing wrong there?

Comment: @cnak2 that code does not work, check my answer & explanation.